# How to get planned work programmatically for TFS iteration?

Tags: tfs, wiql

We are following Scrum process and I want to calculate how many PBIs were actually considered or added during each iteration of release? For e.g. on day 1 of Iteration1 I have 10 PBIs and added 5 more till last day of Iteration 1. So I should get planned PBIs as 15, no matter how many were removed, Done or moved to backlog / next sprint.
I am able to get work items in my C# application and tried to loop through WI Revisions but I am not getting it correct.

How to achieve this either through TFS WIQL or TFS APIs?

Comment: Can you elaborate the criteria to count or not count the PBI? Is it the Creation Date or if the work item was ever assigned to a specific iteration?

Comment: How about the asof clause to check the list of Work Items under the Iteration Path each day?  You have to use the api to use asof as it's not available in the query editor.  

If you had a start date variable passed into a query so it worked out as something like:

SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE ([System.IterationPath] = 'MyProject\Release1\Sprint1' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item') asof '01/06/15 00:00'

You could stick the returned IDs in a list, then add a day to your date value and re-run the query, adding any new IDs to the list. Repeat until the finish date.

Comment: Thanks Giulio. Creation date may be earlier date (available in backlog) but as you said "if the work item was ever assigned to a specific iteration", I want this data.

Comment: Thanks  rerwinRR, I am able to execute the query as you suggested and I can see data as I wanted but it is very slow. I am collecting data for all releases querying WI for each date is very time consuming. Is there any way to get it fast?